# how to test a hotfolder that use channels in spring-integration?

Tags: testing, jakarta-ee, spring-integration, channel

in spring-integretion project,i have a hot folder that detects when a csv is placed in a folder and do some extra stuff, i have a inbound-channel-adapter connected with a channel.

inbound-channel-adapter           ->        channel.
detects when a csv its placed                receive the mns its connected with
                                              a service-activator
what i what to do its test only that the channel its receiving the mns when a file its created

i am using this tutorial 
https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/05/spring-integration-file-polling-and-tests.html
its very useful, but i can create the context

> > Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@57a4d5ee] to prepare test instance [proyect.integration.hotFolderTest@5af5def9]
> >     java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext

Answer (score 1):

You need to show more stack trace on the matter, because right now it isn't clear what is your real issue.

Also would be great to share some code what you have so far and what you would like to do in the test case.

To verify a message presence in the channel you can configure a `ChannelInterceptor` and implement its `preSend()`.

However we also suggest something like `@SpringIntegrationTest` with the `MockIntegration` features. That way you can replace your real service activator with some `MockIntegration.mockMessageHandler()` and perform verification on it.

You would need to configure a `noAutoStartup` on the mentioned annotation do not poll directory until you prepare your mock and call a `this.mockIntegrationContext.substituteMessageHandlerFor()`.

See more info in the Reference Manual: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/testing.html#test-context

Comment: hi, now i know that my problem was, that first of all i need to verify that all the context (that i define  in a xml) it needs to be loaded in the test class that i create with:
>@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
   @ContextConfiguration(locations =
{ "/../resources/hot-folder.xml" })
Artem Bilan you are right my question its very general, that was beacuse i didn't know what i was doing.

Comment: but the thing is that with RunWith you specify the special runner of spring and with ContextConfiguration you specify the locations, or class you need to load your context, in my case i bring all the beans in the path /../resources/hot-folder.xml so i can used in the test, and you have to verify that this beans were create well before you bring your context